# Parse excel line

Tags: excel

I'm working on the metrics for my team. I receive a line like this:

```
*Event <"number"> initiated. Msg: Tkt:xxxx/Severity/Impact:<"prod/cert">/Client:<"client">/Sys:<"server_name">/Prob:<"description"> :/Esc.Team:<team>/Start@<time>*
```

I'm able to parse most of the important things Impact, Severity, Client and Team.

But I need to get the server name. Basically I need to copy the server name from that line to a column.

Is that possible?

Comment: How are you getting Impact, Severity, Client, and Team?  Why can't you do the same for server name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the format of the string is stable then a mix of `mid` and `find` should do it.

If the string is in cell `A1`:

```
=MID(A1;FIND("/Sys:<";A1)+7;FIND(">/Prob:";A1)-FIND("/Sys:<";A1)-8)
```

Would extract `server_name`

I'm sure there's a smarter way, but my I don't excel at Excel (pun intended :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy into a new column, Find & Replace for the column:

Find what:

```
*Sys:<"
```

Replace All, Find what:

```
"*
```

Replace All.